# PHP SPL - is there any interface or class to control what happens when casting to array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, spl

So by implementing `Iterator`, `ArrayAccess`, and `Countable` built-in interfaces, we have control over what happens inside an object when it's used in `foreach` loops or if a property is accessed as if it were an array index (`$object['id']`).

For example, if you wanted, you could set it up so `$object['version'] += 1` could automatically increment `version` field in the database.

What's missing is casting the `object` to `array`.  Is there any interface or class that allows control over what happens when you do: `(array) $object`?  Any *built-in* interface or class at all, no matter how obscure?  For example: if I wanted `(array) $object` to return `$this->propertyArray` instead of the normal object to array conversion of dumping all public object properties?

Note: something like requiring calling `$object->toArray()` by method name doesn't count, as the idea is to minimize the *outside* differences between an array and object as much as possible.

Comment: What does casting it give you?

Comment: @alex: just updated question.  Casting gives nothing abnormal... which is the problem.  The idea is overriding casting behavior using SPL extension if possible.

Comment: [`ArrayObject`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) adds upon `ArrayAccess`. But it just provides a `::getArrayCopy()` which is not invoked on casting IIRC. But still it might be your best bet to investigate, foremost with `::ARRAY_AS_PROPS` mode.

Comment: @mario: do you know if `getArrayCopy()` is invoked automagically in any case?  For example, if called automatically on `$array = clone $object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no there is not , because toArray() is not an magic function like __toString(); where casting works e.g

```
$foo = (string) $myObect;
```

you have to specify toArray() and inside it return your array , may be in future __toArray() might come.

Comment: I believe you're right.  I guess I was being too hopeful.  It does look like SPL magic array interfaces are incomplete in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method like this

```
public function toArray() {
    return get_object_vars( $this );
}
```

[See here](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Object-To-Array-With-PHP.html). Or check [SplFixedArray::toArray](http://php.net/manual/de/splfixedarray.toarray.php).

Comment: `SplFixedArray::toArray` is the closest match to what I'm referring to.  But, I was instead hoping there was some magic SPL interface to hook into what happens when an object is cast to array.